# What is the meaning of the symbol $C^\infty$?

Tags: notation, terminology, definition

What is the meaning of the symbol $C^\infty$ (often used in defining a smooth functions)? I'm a student of physics, and my knowledge of mathematical symbols is sloppy.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the set of functions with infinitely many continuous derivatives, that is $C^\infty(A,B)$ is the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ that have continuous derivatives of order $k$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: If $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, the notation $C^\infty(A,B)$ means all partial derivatives of all orders exist (and are continuous).  If $B = \mathbb R$, we may write simply $C^\infty(A)$.